# Upgraded to pandas 0.13.1, getting DeprecationWarning with sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, deprecated

I'm using Python 2.7.3. I just upgraded from Pandas 0.12.0 to 0.13.1, and made no other changes. I upgraded to be able to use the new eval() method in the DataFrame class.

The following code runs perfectly, with no errors or warnings:

```
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
df.eval('a + b')
```

However, if I import any classes from scikit-learn (version 0.14.1), the same code gives me a Deprecation warning. The following code:

```
from sklearn import naive_bayes
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
df.eval('a + b')
```

gives me the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/computation/ops.py:62:DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
return supr_new(klass, name, env, side=side, encoding=encoding)
```

I'm using numpy version 1.6.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Weird, I cannot reproduce that with the master branch of scikit-learn though. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I just forked+built the master branch and I don't get the error, looks like this has been fixed in the latest codebase. Thank you.